# How can I select the row with an id that's depending on a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a row with the `id="row_4"`

I have a javascript variable `rownum` with a value of 4

How can I select using jQuery this element? I tried

`$('#row_' + rownum)`

but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you check the error console in Firefox, Chrome or Safari browser? Any messages did occure? Posting more code is more helpful for the willing helpers.

Comment: did you make sure that you're not calling this before the DOM is ready?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the row?
It could be that your selector is working fine but your processing of it once selected is failing.
If you can show the rest of your code we can probably help more.

Answer (score 2):

if you not getting any error's, then you may calling before page load(as alnitak hinted) try to put in doucment.ready() function.

like this.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   alert($('#row_' + rownum).text());
});
```